# Create a stored procedure which includes return records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure which has 3 parameters. Another software will call my procedure with parameters in order to query a bunch of records.

The stored procedure includes only a `select` statement with a `where` clause filtering according to parameters.

How can I return these records to the "caller"?
I have tried to insert these records in a temp table as follows:

```
create procedure xxx
drop table table_temp
select * into table_temp from table where parameters
```

The thing is, if two users are calling the stored procedure at the same time, they will get mixed up results.

Any suggestion to this dilemma is highly appreciated.

Comment: Temporary tables' names [must start with `#`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables), but it's not clear [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you want a temporary table in the first place instead of just a `select`.

Comment: As @GSerg said, your table isn't a temporary table, it's a physical table in the database that your SP is located in. As a result running multiple instances of the SP at the same time *will* result in undesired behaviour. A real temporary table (prefixed with a single `#`) only persists in the connection it is created in and (just as importantly) can **only** be referenced by the connection it was created in. But, I also see no reason for a temporary table here. Instead of dropping and creating a table (by using the `INTO` operator), just use a `SELECT`.

Comment: How can I return the resulted records to the "caller"?

Comment: `select * from table where parameters`?

Comment: By not using `INTO` and just using a `SELECT`, @NedalAbdouni, as both myself and GSerg suggested. You have no reason for a (Temporary) Table here.

Comment: I had the stored procedure in the first place only configured to do a select, but the result of calling it was resulting only with a "success". Does the caller get the records returned back?

Comment: Yes, @NedalAbdouni. As can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3528b1a964f52ee88ad5d301c247ef1a).

Comment: That depends on how you call the procedure from client code. The records are sent, but apparently you ignore them.

Comment: Seems like what you should be asking about is your application, not the SQL (although the SQL does need addressing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use a temporary table as stated above, or use the table type (I use the AdventureWorks2014 demo database for these examples):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TableVariableDemo(
   @Color nvarchar(15),
   @Size nvarchar(5))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Results TABLE(ProductID int, [Name] nvarchar(255), ProductNumber nvarchar(25), Color nvarchar(15), Size nvarchar(5))

   INSERT INTO @Results (ProductID, [Name], ProductNumber, Color, Size)
   SELECT
      ProductID,
      [Name],
      ProductNumber,
      Color,
      Size
   FROM
      Production.Product
   WHERE
      Color = @Color AND
      Size = @Size

   SELECT
      ProductID,
      [Name],
      ProductNumber,
      Color,
      Size
   FROM
      @Results
END
```

The solution is good when you expect not too much rows being returned. When you expect a lot of rows returned by the query, using a temporary table could be better. The same with using a temporary table:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE TempTableDemo(
    @Color nvarchar(15),
    @Size nvarchar(5))
 AS
 BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE #Results(ProductID int, [Name] nvarchar(255), ProductNumber nvarchar(25), Color nvarchar(15), Size nvarchar(5))

   INSERT INTO #Results (ProductID, [Name], ProductNumber, Color, Size)
   SELECT
      ProductID,
      [Name],
      ProductNumber,
      Color,
      Size
   FROM
      Production.Product
   WHERE
      Color = @Color AND
      Size = @Size

   SELECT
      ProductID,
      [Name],
      ProductNumber,
      Color,
      Size
   FROM
      #Results

   DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

But I wonder why you don't use something like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SelectDemo(
    @Color nvarchar(15),
    @Size nvarchar(5))
 AS
 BEGIN
   SELECT
      ProductID,
      [Name],
      ProductNumber,
      Color,
      Size
   FROM
      Production.Product
   WHERE
      Color = @Color AND
      Size = @Size
END
```

Best wishes
Michael